# How to save additional column field in core table in magento 2

Tags: database, save, magento2.2.2, product-review

**I have created custom module for product review. I have added additional coloumn in review_detail table in DB. I got all submitted values from form including my custom column value in Controller. But Now How Do I Save the additional column value in DB which means how do I pass the value to DB to that associated created column**

```
 public function execute()
    {
        $message = null;
        $status = null;
        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $message = __("Invalid form key");
            $status = 'failed';
        } else {
            //get the form data
            $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);
            if ($data) {
                $rating = [];
                if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                    $rating = $data['ratings'];
                }
            } else {
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

                $detail = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('detail');
                $data['detail'] = trim($detail);
                $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
            }
            if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
                /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */

                $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);
                $review->unsetData('review_id');
                $validate = $review->validate();
                if ($validate === true) {
                    try {
                        $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                                ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                                ->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                                ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                                ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                                ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                                ->save();
                        foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                            $this->ratingFactory->create()
                                    ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                                    ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                                    ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                                    ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                        }
                        $review->aggregate();
                        $status = 'success';
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                        $message = __('We can\'t post your review right now.');
                        $status = 'failed';
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                    if (is_array($validate)) {
                        foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                            $message = $errorMessage;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $message = __('We can\'t post your review right now.');
                    }
                    $status = 'failed';
                }
            }
        }
        $result['messages'] = $message;
        $result['status'] = $status;
        $resultJson = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultJson->setData($result);
        return $resultJson;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the best solution is to create a plugin to the review model

You could create a `beforeSave` method and check if your parameters are being submitted. If so, you just set the parameters you want e.g.: `$subject->setData('mydata', 'myvalue')`

After that, all your custom date should be saved automatically.

For more information, check [Magento devDocs - Plugins (Interceptors)](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#before-methods)

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have saved my additional field value in DB

Comment: Now i need to get that field value in list.phtml which shows the existing customer reviews in product page

Comment: I have got the collection. But failed to get my additional field value

Comment: try using the `getCustomAttribute` method e.g.:

 `$model->getCustomAttribute('your_attribute_name'); if ($attribute) { $value =  $attribute->getValue(); } `

Comment: @Sri Could you set this answer as correct?